# Flutter: State management

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate, bloc, state-management

I've seen many tutorials praising Bloc State management, what is so special about it and should I learn it as a beginner? if not is there any beginner friendly state management technique?

Comment: Start with provider is the most suitable for beginners and small applications, bloc also makes use of provider but with a more robust architecture.

Comment: Alright @Chance.. I'll check it out. What about Getx? is it any good?

Comment: I did maintenance on a project that had GetX and it bothered me a lot as it is architecture, I see Getx as a box that has everything even what is not necessary, it is a cannon to kill a fly. See some example of Getx and draw your own conclusions, it's the best way.

Comment: try provider>> Riverpod>> Bloc

Comment: GetX or Cubit. I personally liked Getx which gives me complete control over the project.

Comment: Been researching GetX for the past week, I'm surprised with how easier it's learning curve is. Compared to other statemanagement options.. @JabeedAhmed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## BLoC/Cubit

BLoC is great for *complex* state management for *complex* apps. However, inside the BLoC library there's a simpler way of managing state that's called Cubit (Cubit is sort of a subset of BLoC). Cubit is largely the same as BLoC except:

1. less boilerplate
2. doesn't use 2-way streams

This renders it much easier to learn, and a fantastic stepping-stone into a full-out BLoC driven state management solution.

Currently, my team and I are building a very complex app, and we use the principle: use Cubits, unless there's a *specific* reason to use a BLoC. This has worked well for us (90% of our app is run with Cubit, 10% with BLoC).

---

In relation to other state management techniques, most people are probably going to recommend Provider or Riverpods (Riverpods = Provider on steroids). They **are** easier to learn than Cubit/BLoC — **except only for simple cases** (a few page app). Once your app gets complex (authentication, feeds, api calls, etc.) a Cubit/BLoC-based architecture is going to scale better and be much cleaner.

Additionally, the most-used state management system for production-level Flutter apps is BLoC/Cubit. So, if you're looking for a marketable skill, I'd default to that.

## Helpful links:

- [Flutter package that contains BOTH BLoC and Cubit](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc).
- [The tutorial series I watched to learn BLoC/Cubit (and recommend!).](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THCkkQ-V1-8)
- [I **HIGHLY** recommend watching this series as well that shows **WHERE** to put your BLoC/Cubit in an app to align with best practices and clean architecture.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dc3B_mMrZ-Q)

## Example app (understanding this will help you a lot):

Here's a [simple 1-feature app](https://github.com/mattrltrent/clean_architecture_weather_app) I made as a proof of concept to show how Cubit specifically works. Read the project's `README.md` for context (star it? ).

## Conclusion:

Provider, GetX, Riverpods, etc. are all easier to learn and contain less boilerplate than BLoC, except they won't scale as well when your app gets more complex.

To help combat the boilerplate/complexity problem of BLoC, use Cubits instead of BLoCs in your design unless you have a specific need for BLoCs.

Answer (score 1):

## GETX - State Management

I would suggest Getx as I have been using it for **3 years** and it's incredible.

It is effortless to learn.

I never encountered a need to use any other state management.

### Features provided by GETX

- State management
- Dependency Injection
- Theming
- Clean Structure
- Internationalization
- Validation / Utils

[Documentation](https://chornthorn.github.io/getx-docs/docs/)

Answer (score 1):

Cubits are quite easy to understand and can be used in most of the Flutter projects. For bigger apps I would go for Riverpod. Having independent providers gives a lot of flexibility, as they can be used in different parts of the app and you can make any future, use case or repository a provider.

I have wrote a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/flutter-list-details-app-with-cubits-hooks-and-hive-database-2e87be09b580) with Flutter app on how to write a List - Details app using cubits, hooks and local database with Hive.